# How to Redirect to URL Onclick after upload is complete?

Tags: jquery, firebase, onclick, progress-bar, onclicklistener

```
$("#fileThumbnail").on("change", function(event) {
  selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

});

function uploadThumb() {

  var filename = selectedFile.name;
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/Thumbs/' + filename);
  var uploadThumb = storageRef.put(selectedFile);

  uploadThumb.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot){
    var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    uploader.value = percentage;

    $('.thumbsubmit-btn').click(function() {
      window.location.href = 'index.html';
      return false;
    });


  }, function(error) {

  }, function () {

  });
}
```

I am trying to redirect to another url on click but after the upload is complete. 
How do I do that? The progress bar is working and the files are being uploaded aswell.
just dont know how do I add this redirect to my function, so that the button uploads the file
and then triggers a redirect once the upload is complete.

Comment: Try to use promises. It should be an async operation. If one function is ending, then start another. 

You can check this article:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#fileThumbnail").on("change", function(event) {
  selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

});

function uploadThumb() {

  var filename = selectedFile.name;
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/Thumbs/' + filename);
  var uploadThumb = storageRef.put(selectedFile);

  uploadThumb.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot){
    var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    uploader.value = percentage;

    $('.thumbsubmit-btn').click(function() {
      window.location.href = 'index.html';
      return false;
    });


  }, function(error) {

  }, function () {
window.location.href = "index.html";
  });
}
```

So I figured it out. Just added **window.location.href = "index.html";** on the last function